Wallet tracking trouble
I have successfully tracked my wallet balances, and subscribed to the transaction tracking.
I keep getting the following error message when I make a transaction on the wallet.
Subscribed to wallet AcsUpwP4Dxt8PHqMuunw7FgQDYTPmtRh4U1BdUZ2kksf with subscription ID: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":9190858,"id":1}

Error parsing message: 'signature'

Message: {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'accountNotification', 'params': {'result': {'context': {'slot': 298236797}, 'value': {'lamports': 979076666, 'data': ['', 'base64'], 'owner': '11111111111111111111111111111111', 'executable': False, 'rentEpoch': 18446744073709551615, 'space': 0}}, 'subscription': 9190858}}

This is my code,
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.types import TokenAccountOpts
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
import base58

# Define the wallet address directly in the code
wallet_address = "AcsUpwP4Dxt8PHqMuunw7FgQDYTPmtRh4U1BdUZ2kksf"

# Initialize the Solana client
solana_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

async def get_token_accounts(wallet_pubkey):
    async with AsyncClient("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com") as client:
        resp = await client.get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed(
            wallet_pubkey,
            TokenAccountOpts(program_id=Pubkey(base58.b58decode('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'))),
            commitment=Confirmed
        )
        resp = resp.to_json()
        resp_json = json.loads(resp)
        return resp_json['result']['value']

async def get_transaction_details(signature):
    async with AsyncClient("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com") as client:
        resp = await client.get_transaction(signature)
        return resp.value

async def track_transactions(wallet_pubkey):
    uri = "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        subscription_message = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": 1,
            "method": "accountSubscribe",
            "params": [
                str(wallet_pubkey),
                {
                    "encoding": "jsonParsed",
                    "commitment": "confirmed"
                }
            ]
        }
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(subscription_message))
        subscription_id = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"Subscribed to wallet {wallet_address} with subscription ID: {subscription_id}")

        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            message_json = json.loads(message)
            if 'params' in message_json and 'result' in message_json['params']:
                try:
                    tx_signature = message_json['params']['result']['value']['signature']
                    tx_details = await get_transaction_details(tx_signature)
                    print(f"New Transaction Signature: {tx_signature}")
                    print(f"Transaction Details: {json.dumps(tx_details, indent=4)}")
                except KeyError as e:
                    print(f"Error parsing message: {e}")
                    print(f"Message: {message_json}")

def get_wallet_balance():
    try:
        # Convert the wallet address to a Pubkey object
        wallet_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(wallet_address)

        # Get the balance of the wallet in SOL
        balance_info = solana_client.get_balance(wallet_pubkey)
        balance_lamports = balance_info.value  # Directly access 'value' attribute
        balance_sol = balance_lamports / 1e9  # Convert lamports to SOL
        print(f"The balance of wallet {wallet_address} is {balance_sol} SOL.")
        
        # Get token accounts
        token_accounts = asyncio.run(get_token_accounts(wallet_pubkey))
        for account in token_accounts:
            token_balance = account['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['tokenAmount']['uiAmount']
            token_mint = account['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['mint']
            print(f"Token: {token_mint}, Balance: {token_balance}")
        
        # Start tracking transactions
        asyncio.run(track_transactions(wallet_pubkey))
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Solana Wallet Tracker!")
    # Get and print the balance of the specified wallet
    get_wallet_balance()
    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Any help would be awesome.

You have an error because you are trying to find the 'signature' from the json returned by accountSubscribe, which in fact, as you can see from the message_json, does not contain it at all. if you want to listen to transactions you have to use the ws method logsubscribe. the accountsubscribe method is used to receive notifications when the lamports or data changes.

thank you very much
